# How to lock phone in portrait mode with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, landscape-portrait, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm making an application in SwiftUI and I don't want the user to be able to rotate their screen and be able to view the app in landscape mode. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Click on your project name with the blue icon next to it in Xcode.
2. Select the "TARGETS" version of your project.
3. Under "Deployment Info" in the General tab, change the "Device Orientation" settings.

Comment: "Development info" should read "Deployment Info"...

Comment: @RudyF Thanks for pointing it out, was just a typo

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative solution:**

If the simple options on *Project > Target > General > Deployment Info > Device Orientation* are not enough for you, then try the following:

1. Go to your project settings by selecting your project in Project Navigator.

[image]

2. Select a target in the "TARGETS" section.
3. Go to the "Info" tab.
4. There are 3 arrays you may have to adjust: "Supported interface orientations (iPhone)", "Supported interface orientations", "Supported interface orientations (iPad)"

[image]

Comment: The plist just reflects the settings in the general tab

Comment: You're right, haven't noticed that. I'll reformulate my answer as an alternative solution. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out this alternative approach is the only way to set device orientation. The approach in the accepted answer doesn't work in Xcode 13 (it's said it's a bug with Xcode 13).